# Hover Slam Landing: How is it Done?

Tags: launch, falcon-9, blue-origin, vertical-landing

I want to simulate a hover slam landing.

Is there an overview of the maneuver anywhere?

I'm especially interested in the control algorithm used to bring the rocket stage to a halt at just the right time. I don't care much for location control (where the landing happens)---I just want to land the rocket stage *somewhere* *anywhere*.

The algorithm must account for both altitude and velocity left to kill before touching ground and estimate how much time to go, when to fire the engine, how long to fire it for, and maybe the appropriate throttle level to stick the landing.

The estimates should reflect the effects of gravity, thrust, and drag (drag being an important complication not dealt with during PEG as that occurs in near vacuum).

Anyone know how the calculations might go?

Comment: Easy, just launch the rocket in your simulation, then play it backwards.

Comment: Ha ha ha. That’s one strategy :D

Comment: Why look for a harder strategy if this works? Is there some part of the problem that this would not solve?

Comment: Look for the game KSP that will let you practice this

Comment: There are some significant differences vs launch. In particular, amount of fuel (->mass) changes in the opposite direction. But the essence is pretty much this - record the speed and altitude of the rocket when launching on 3 engines with nearly empty tank and at some 70% throttle, until you reach the same speed upwards as terminal velocity downwards. Then replay it backwards, regulating thrust to stay close to the same profile.

Comment: You really only need a couple basic kinematics like $F = m * a$. Its not hard to simulate a hoverslam, the difficulty is getting your hardware to actually do it error-free....

Comment: No. It's not that simple. The rocket stage doesn't land on F = m * a alone. You need to estimate how long to fire and when to start the engine and actively adjust the throttle to hit the landing pad at near zero velocity just as your altitude hits zero. And you need to factor in drag, gravity, and thrust along with inertia. It most decidedly is not just a simple F = m*a.

Comment: Mind you I'm not trying to specify the hoverslam trajectory explicitly. I'm controlling my engine throttle and my thrust vector, but it's the whole physics of the model that determine where the rocket goes. I get to start the engines and set the thrust level and rotate the engine nozzles but that is all the control I have. So it's not simple kinematics.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is yet another question about SpaceX where a definitive answer almost certainly will not be forthcoming. SpaceX is very protective of its intellectual property, and this IP represents a huge investment by SpaceX, certainly well into in the tens of millions of dollars.

Comment: That strategy doesn't work, @uhoh. A launch vehicle gets heavier when played backwards. On the other hand, a landing vehicle gets lighter as it approaches the landing site.

Comment: @DavidHammen since my comment begins "Easy, just..." one knows right off the bat that it's not a serious proposal. If one put a minus sign in front of $\dot{m}$ and started the sim with near-empty tanks, what would be the next problem?

Comment: David, SpaceX doesn't own the hover slam concept. Anyone who figures it out can do it. And SpaceX isn't the only one who's researched this. In fact, odds are, they simply copied bits and pieces from others who'd researched and developed this before. They copy lots of things. So it matters nothing that SpaceX doesn't share it. There are space minds outside of SpaceX who know this stuff. Some of those minds hang around stackexchange. So my question is to them: how is a hover slam done? This isn't about SpaceX, and my falcon-9 tag is there only because it's one of several self-landing rockets.

Comment: Good point on the difference between a launch and playing back a launch, though. That difference in the change in mass would make a big difference.

Comment: But really it peeves me that we should shy away from figuring things out because some corporation "owns" the tech. Good for them. Now let's figure it out :P

Comment: http://www.larsblackmore.com/iee_tcst13.pdf

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing official from SpaceX so any algorithm will be based on assumptions. Unlike your question SpaceX will be very interested indeed in exactly where their rocket lands and they will also have to work in 3 dimensions.

A simplified and approximate algorithm should be possible to build “relatively” easily. I would assume each phase of the landing will have target parameters, so on final descent the rocket should already be at a specific location, velocity and acceleration plus or minus a margin.

The side thrusters and Merlin engine gimbaling will be used to position the rocket to the right location directly above the landing pad.

The key thing to remember is that the Merlin engine can’t throttle down sufficiently to make a nearly empty Falcon stage hover. In other words the engine thrust pushing the rocket up is *always* more than the force of gravity pulling it down. If it weren’t for the fact that the rocket already had considerable velocity towards the ground it would accelerate back up in the air.

So the calculation that must be made is to ensure the upwardly accelerating rocket eats through its downward velocity in such a way that the velocity equals zero at the same time as the rocket reaches zero altitude and the engine is cut off. This calculation requires the use of the laws of motion and must take into account the rate of propellant consumption and the decreasing mass of the rocket.